What Makes Commitment Loss to Increase in VQ Training?
I am trying to train a residual VQ-VAE on some noisy time-series data. I observed that there will always be a point where the commitment loss (CLoss) will start to increase while the reconstruction loss (TDLoss) decrease faster. See the screenshots below between 10k to 15k steps. The number of steps before this happening seems related to the weight associated with the commitment loss, a smaller weight will make this turning point to happen earlier. I wonder what potentially could cause this, and whether this is a good thing or not.


